# Adding custom field in all widgets, but at the top of the form, in admin area

Tags: customization, widgets, forms, code

I am creating a cute new functionality on my theme that requires to add a custom field to all widgets forms in the admin area. I managed to do so by using the in_widget_form hook:

```
function thefunction($t,$return,$instance){
    $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, array( 'thefield' => ''));
    if(isset($instance['thefield'])){
        $instance['thefield'] = null;
    }
    ?>
    <p>
        
        <label for="<?php echo $t->get_field_id('thefield'); ?>">
            <?php _e('Field label: ',''); ?>&nbsp;
        </label>
        <input id="<?php echo $t->get_field_id('thefield'); ?>" type="text" name="<?php echo $t->get_field_name('thefield'); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
    $retrun = null;
    return array($t,$return,$instance);
}
add_action('in_widget_form', 'thefunction',5,3);
```

Now, I am getting the form field on every widget, but it is displaying at the bottom.

Is there a way to display it at the top?